# How to get notices about filtered results using Google Custom Search API

Tags: google-custom-search

When searching on the Google website, sometimes we see the message "Some results may have been removed under data protection law in Europe" at the bottom of the page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTCMy.png

Is there a way to get this message when searching with Google Custom Search API? https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list

I checked the API documentation and didn't see any related information.